# Using Ajax in .NET 2.0

Tags: .net, ajax, sql-server-2005

im new to ajax and i can use ajax in framework 3.5 like update panel. but im unable using in 2.0. give me some intructions to follow. actually i need to run a asp web control in ajax envirment in .net 2.0. does anyone know the solution, let me know. thankx..

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Refer this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/AJAXASPNET20.aspx). It will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX Pro free library. Many used it even before ASP.NET AJAX
http://www.ajaxpro.info/

Also, you can download ASP.NET AJAX 1.0, that is created for ASP.NET 2.0
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en

I expect you to have bad time with both looking for old documentation and having bugs solved only in newer versions, etc, so, it may be better to start learning something like jQuery and depend on it more.

**Update**
If you are using ASP.NEXT AJAX 1.0, this seems the latest version of ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit that targets ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/4923

**Update2** As mentioned in another answer, ASP.NET has sort of built-in AJAX support via callbacks, which works for some basic scenarios and even has a bit of support on GridView I guess (AllowCallback property or something like this), but I don't think it'll be easy to depend on it for many scenarios (if at all enough).

Answer (score 0):

There's an ajax toolkit for .net 2.0 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en Maybe this is what you need